# barplot column for <NA>

Tags: r, bar-chart, na

I would like to have a column in my barplot for missing data.

```
adult <- read.csv(
    "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data", 
    header = FALSE, 
    na.strings = "?", 
    strip.white = TRUE
)
colnames(adult) <- c("age", "workClass", "fnlwgt", "education", "educationNum", "maritalStatus", "occupation", "relationship", "race", "sex", "capitalGain", "capitalLoss", "hoursPerWeek", "nativeCountry", "prediction")
barplot(table(adult$workClass), main="Job Distribution", xlab="Job", ylab="Count",las=2)
```

I know that in this dataset, there are 1836 missing values for `workClass`, from

```
length(which(is.na(adult$workClass)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the argument `useNA = "ifany"` in `table`.

```
tab <- table(adult$workClass, useNA = "ifany")
#  Federal-gov        Local-gov     Never-worked          Private 
#          960             2093                7            22696 
# Self-emp-inc Self-emp-not-inc        State-gov      Without-pay 
#         1116             2541             1298               14 
#         <NA> 
#         1836
```

By default, the name of the `NA` count is `NA` itself. You can change the name to the character string `"NA"` with the following command.

```
names(tab)[is.na(names(tab))] <- "NA"
```

Now, the plot displays the name `"NA"` on the *x* axis too.

```
barplot(tab, main = "Job Distribution", xlab = "Job", ylab = "Count", las = 2)
```

Comment: How do I make the barplot have a column name for NA? It's blank by default, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `useNA = "ifany"` in `table()` and `names.arg` in `barplot()`

```
barplot(table(adult$workClass, useNA = "ifany"),
        names.arg = c(levels(adult$workClass),"NA's") )
```

`c(levels(adult$workClass),"NA's")` Is creating a vector that includes the names of all the levels/categories within the variable and the custom name `NA's` to represent the NA values